# Defining cells in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a macro that allows a user to enter a new banknote serial number. The macro requires 3 inputs (currency, denomination and serial number). I'm a beginner to VBA, but the code I tried to write is below. Can anyone point out where I went wrong, or what needs to be changed to make it work? Thanks!

```
Sub TestSub()
Dim Note_Serial As Variant
Dim Note_Currency As Variant
Dim Note_Denomination As Variant
'Defining 3 inputs

Note_Currency = InputBox("Enter Currency (in 3 letter form):")
Note_Denomination = InputBox("Enter Note Denomination (with $ sign):")
Note_Serial = InputBox("Enter Serial Number:")
'Getting 3 inputs

Dim Currency_Cell As Range
Dim Denomination_Cell As Range
Dim Serial_Cell As Range
'Defining cells to write inputs

Currency_Cell = (D3)
Denomination_Cell = (E3)
Serial_Cell = (F3)
'Starting cells

Currency_Cell = Note_Currency
Denomination_Cell = Note_Denomination
Serial_Cell = Note_Serial
'Writing inputs to spreadsheet

Currency_Cell.Offset (1)
Denomination_Cell.Offset (1)
Serial_Cell.Offset (1)
'Moving all cells down 1 place
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of writing `Currency_Cell = (D3)`, you want to write `Set Currency_Cell = Range("D3")` (Assuming that you don't switch the active Worksheet).

EDIT: To prevent overwriting previously entered data, use instead:

```
Set Currency_Cell = Cells(Rows.Count, Range("D3").Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
```

This will select the first empty Cell in Column D.

To move the cell reference, you have to also use the `Set` keyword, and give the offset in rows and columns:

```
Set Currency_Cell = Currency_Cell.Offset (1, 0)
```

Comment: Thank you! The inputs now work and write to the correct cells. However, when I enter a second note, it overwrites the first note. Can you explain why this is happening? Thanks again

Comment: That's because you always start in row 3, overwriting previously written data. I've updated my answer to prevent that.